# option value to li

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-lists

How do i convert this line of code to eg,  `<li>DE</li>`

```
optionlist.Append("<option value=\"" +
                  DB.RSField(rs, "Name") +
                  "\" " +
                  CommonLogic.IIF(currentLocaleSetting == DB.RSField(rs, "Name"), " selected ", String.Empty) +
                  ">" +
                  DB.RSField(rs, "Description") +
                  "</option>");
```

I also tried this:

```
optionlist.Append("<li>" + "a href=" + 
"/setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&localesetting=" + DB.RSField(rs, "Name") +
 "</a>" + CommonLogic.IIF(currentLocaleSetting == DB.RSField(rs, "Name"), "", String.Empty) + "" + DB.RSField(rs, "Description") + "</li>");
```

But this creates the the following which is WRONG:

`a href=/setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&localesetting=de-DEDeutsch`

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: tried changing option value to <li> but my code has selected which i dont need?

Comment: They are pretty different concepts. For one, LI doesn't have 'selected' and won't be posted back.

Comment: you can't just change the child elements without changing the parent element.  the select should be changed to a <ul> or <ol>

Comment: i have changed the parent element in my code. I didnt want to show you what i already tried because it would be too much code to copy and paste.

Comment: added some edits and things ive tried.

Comment: The code you show misses the `<` at `a href`. I guess it should have been `<a href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should look like this in order to generate list items:

```
optionlist.Append("<ul>");

//loop start here...
optionlist.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", DB.RSField(rs, "Name"));
//loop ends here...

optionlist.Append("</ul>");
```

This will "lose" the description though, so to add it as well:

```
optionlist.Append("<ul>");

//loop start here...
optionlist.AppendFormat("<li>{0} <a href=\"/setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&localesetting={0}\">{1}</a></li>", DB.RSField(rs, "Name"), DB.RSField(rs, "Description"));
//loop ends here...

optionlist.Append("</ul>");
```

The above will show the description next to each name.

Comment: Oh wow! thanks i do need to add the hyperlink `a href=/setlocale.aspx?returnURL=Default.aspx&localesetting=de-DE` but in the description i need to lose the lower case `de-`... I guess its a start, ill have a go at this too and post back. :)

Comment: @sp-1986 see my edit, it should now make the description link as you asked.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this. I can now make many changes else where with the knowledge you have shared with me.

Comment: @sp-1986 cheers, it was pretty basic but we all start somewhere. :)